# Initialize device array in CUDA

Tags: memory-management, cuda

How do I initialize device array which is allocated using `cudaMalloc()`?

I tried `cudaMemset`, but it fails to initialize all values except `0.code`, for cudaMemset looks like below, where value is initialized to 5.

```
cudaMemset(devPtr,value,number_bytes)
```

Comment: Could you provide your code there you call `cudaMemset`?

Comment: You understand that the value in `cudaMemset` is a *byte* value, not a word value, ie. the same as in the C standard library `memset`?

Answer (score 13):

As you are discovering, `cudaMemset` works like the C standard library `memset`. Quoting from the documentation:

```
cudaError_t cudaMemset  (   void *      devPtr,
                            int         value,
                            size_t      count    
                        )
```

> Fills the first count bytes of the memory area pointed to by devPtr
>   with the constant byte value value.

So `value` is a *byte* value. If you do something like:

```
int *devPtr;
cudaMalloc((void **)&devPtr,number_bytes);
const int value = 5;
cudaMemset(devPtr,value,number_bytes);
```

what you are asking to happen is that each *byte* of `devPtr` will be set to 5. If `devPtr` was a an array of integers, the result would be each integer word would have the value 84215045. This is probably not what you had in mind.

Using the runtime API, what you could do is write your own generic kernel to do this. It could be as simple as

```
template<typename T>
__global__ void initKernel(T * devPtr, const T val, const size_t nwords)
{
    int tidx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;

    for(; tidx < nwords; tidx += stride)
        devPtr[tidx] = val;
}
```

(standard disclaimer: written in browser, never compiled, never tested, use at own risk).

Just instantiate the template for the types you need and call it with a suitable grid and block size, paying attention to the last argument now being a *word count*, not a byte count as in `cudaMemset`. This isn't really any different to what `cudaMemset` does anyway, using that API call results in a kernel launch which is do too different to what I posted above.

Alternatively, if you can use the driver API, there is `cuMemsetD16` and `cuMemsetD32`, which do the same thing, but for half and full 32 bit word types. If you need to do set 64 bit or larger types (so doubles or vector types), your best option is to use your own kernel.

Comment: Currently,in my code i'm doing same thing but I wanted way with only cudaMemset.

Comment: @user997704: There isn't a way with `cudaMemset`. Either run a kernel of your own, or use `cuMemsetD32`/`cuMemsetD32` from the driver API

Comment: It would be nice for self containment what would be a sensible grid and block size to invoke such kernel e.g. if my array is N=2333 how would I call this kernel?

Comment: I actually don't really understand the stride loop. Why you need a loop at all? Shouldn't each thread set one element and be done with it?

Comment: @GiovanniAzua I believe the stride is there to have one thread initialize more than one element in the array. Sometimes is better to give more work to a thread than launching a lot of threads.

Answer (score 1):

I also needed a solution to this question and I didn't really understand the other proposed solution. Particularly I didn't understand why it iterates over the grid blocks `for(; tidx < nwords; tidx += stride)` and for that matter, the kernel invocation and why using the counter-intuitive word sizes.

Therefore I created a much simpler monolithic generic kernel and customized it with strides i.e. you may use it to initialize a matrix in multiple ways e.g. set rows or columns to any value:

```
template <typename T>
__global__ void kernelInitializeArray(T* __restrict__ a, const T value, 
   const size_t n, const size_t incx) {
      int tid = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
      if (tid*incx < n) {
           a[tid*incx] = value;
       }
}
```

Then you may invoke the kernel like this:

```
template <typename T>
void deviceInitializeArray(T* a, const T value, const size_t n, const size_t incx) {
      int number_of_blocks = ((n / incx) + BLOCK_SIZE - 1) / BLOCK_SIZE;
      dim3 gridDim(number_of_blocks, 1);
      dim3 blockDim(BLOCK_SIZE, 1);
      kernelInitializeArray<T> <<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(a, value, n, incx);
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340927/681865) if you want to understand why the loop is a good idea.