# What's the 'right' way to implement a 32-bit memset for CUDA?

Tags: c++, cuda, memset

CUDA has the API call

```
cudaError_t cudaMemset (void *devPtr, int value, size_t count)
```

which fills a buffer with a single-byte value. I want to fill it with a multi-byte value. Suppose, for the sake of simplicity, that I want to fill `devPtr` with a 32-bit (4-byte) value, and suppose we can ignore endianness. Now, the CUDA driver has the following API call:

```
CUresult cuMemsetD32(CUdeviceptr dstDevice, unsigned int ui, size_t N)
```

So is it enough for me to just: obtain the `CUdeviceptr` from the device-memory-space pointer, then make the driver API call? Or is there something else I need to be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of about CUDA 3.0, runtime API device pointers (and everything else) are interoperable with the driver API. So yes, you can use `cuMemsetD32` to fill a runtime API allocation with a 32 bit value. The size of `CUdeviceptr` will match the size of `void *`on you platform and it is safe to cast a pointer from the CUDA API to `CUdeviceptr` or *vice versa*.

Comment: But a `CUdeviceptr` is an unsigned int, isn't it? can I just cast it as a `void*` ?

Comment: Yes, on 32-bit operating systems CUdeviceptr is an unsigned int (unsigned long long on 64-bit systems), but you can cast it to void* or what ever type your array is.

Comment: @einpoklum: See my edit. You can read more (and see me get schooled by one of the original CUDA developers) [here](http://blog.cudahandbook.com/2013/08/12/why-does-cuda-cudeviceptr-use-unsigned-int-instead-of-void.aspx).

Comment: Even after reading the discussion here and the blog post, it's not clear to me how the cast from unsigned int (32 bit) could possibly work on the latest NVidia GPUs which have up to 10GB of on-board memory.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [talonmies' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22484295/1593077), it seems a reasonable (though ugly) approach would be:

```
#include <stdint.h>
inline cudaError_t cudaMemsetTyped<T>(void *devPtr, T value, size_t count);

#define INSTANTIATE_CUDA_MEMSET_TYPED(_nbits) \
inline cudaError_t cudaMemsetTyped<int ## _nbits ## _t>(void *devPtr, int ## _nbits ## _t value, size_t count) { \
    cuMemsetD ## _nbits( reinterpret_cast<CUdeviceptr>(devPtr), value, count); \
} \
inline cudaError_t cudaMemsetTyped<uint ## _nbits ## _t>(void *devPtr, uint ## _nbits ## _t value, size_t count) { \
    cuMemsetD ## _nbits( reinterpret_cast<CUdeviceptr>(devPtr), reinterpret_cast<uint ## _nbits ## _t>(value), count); \
} \

INSTANTIATE_CUDA_MEMSET_TYPED(8)
INSTANTIATE_CUDA_MEMSET_TYPED(16)
INSTANTIATE_CUD_AMEMSET_TYPED(32)

#undef INSTANTIATE_CUDA_MEMSET_TYPED(_nbits)

inline cudaError_t cudaMemsetTyped<float>(void *devPtr, float value, size_t count) {
    cuMemsetD32( reinterpret_cast<CUdeviceptr>(devPtr), reinterpret_cast<int>(value), count);
}
```

(no `cuMemset64` it seems, so no `double` either)

Comment: To be honest, you will probably find it easier and more performant to do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10599189/681865) if you want to do 64 bit or larger types or a generic template solution

Comment: Yeah, for 64 bit values I suppose I'd need a kernel (unless the hardware supports strided writes). But for upto 32 bits, the driver call should be much faster

Comment: The driver call just launches a kernel, in some circumstances it certainly used to be possible to outperform cudaMemset with a customised memset kernel. You might want to try benchmarking and see.

Comment: @talonmies: Surely you jest... are you telling me I can't just turn off the power to some of the DRAM and zero it? That I have to actually write 0's everywhere? I find that somewhat hard to believe.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. My point is that device memset and device to device memcpy are implmented as kernels on the GPU, and, depending on you use case and data type, it is possible to write custom code which will perform as well as or even better than the generic code the driver launches.