# initialize device array in cuda to a value swiftly

Tags: arrays, cuda, initialization

I am writing particle engine in cuda C, I am in need to initialize huge array to a specific value and with low possible time expense. Currently my array size is 32461759 and will be increasing.. How can I initialize array that size..

In short, I want fastest method to initialize huge array
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to initialize `int` or `float` types to arbitrary values, the fastest method will probably be to use `cuMemsetD32` from [the driver API](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__MEM.html#group__CUDA__MEM_1g983e8d8759acd1b64326317481fbf132).

Additional details and discussion are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483955/whats-the-right-way-to-implement-a-32-bit-memset-for-cuda)

If you simply need to initialize `int`, `float`, or `double` quantities to zero (only), you can use [cudaMemset](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1ge07c97b96efd09abaeb3ca3b5f8da4ee).